# Excel VBA iterate solver through various target constraints

Tags: vba, excel, solver

I am new to the VBA coding and I am trying to write a VBA code.
It should try to create an efficient frontier, so solve for a target volatility (constraints 1 to 20) and maximize the portfolio expected return.
The code should be modified so thatSolver can iterate through a range of target portfolio volatilities to generate the efficient frontier.

The code looks as following:

```
Sub efficient_frontier_solver()

Dim rngobjectCells As Range
Set rngobjectCells = Range("R4:R23")
Dim rngObjectcell As Range
For Each rngObjectcell In rngobjectCells

SolverReset
    SolverOk SetCell:=rngObjectcell.Address, MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=rngObjectcell.Address, _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverAdd CellRef:=rngObjectcell.Address, Relation:=2, FormulaText:=rngObjectcell.Address
    SolverOk SetCell:=rngObjectcell.Address, MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=rngObjectcell.Address, _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverOk SetCell:=rngObjectcell.Address, MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=rngObjectcell.Address, _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve
    Next

End Sub
```

It gives an error, variable not defined.
Can anybody please assist?

Kind regards,

Frederik

Comment: What are the details of the functions SolverReset, Ok, Add and Solve as you are referring to code not detailed in your question?

Comment: Re "It gives an error, variable not defined", I assume that is when you compile (you did try to compile, didn't you)? If not compiling first, then do it and it will show you what is undefined. If during run time, then PLEASE tell us what line of code...

Comment: @Matt_Roberts ever worked with Solver?

Comment: @FrederikT , your objectivecell and variable cell are same in the code. Are you able to run the solver on this configuration manually?